# Issue with installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django

Trying, to figure out why make fails while installing `mod_wsgi` and getting following errors.

Can anyone help me out with to figure out what is wrong ?

```
mod_wsgi.c:13910: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13910: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13915: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:8742: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13915: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13915: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13919: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:13921: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:8778: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13921: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13921: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13923: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:8509: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13923: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:8509: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13923: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:13924: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:13921: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13924: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13924: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:13924: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13926: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:13928: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:8688: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13928: error: redefinition of 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13928: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13929: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:13929: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13930: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:13930: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8769: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13930: error: redefinition of 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13930: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13932: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:13932: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8511: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13932: error: redefinition of 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13932: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13934: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:13932: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13934: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13934: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a c ast
mod_wsgi.c:13934: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:13934: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13936: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:13939: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13939: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13940: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:13928: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13940: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13940: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:13940: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13941: error: conflicting types for 'sequence'
mod_wsgi.c:13929: error: previous definition of 'sequence' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13941: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:13941: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13942: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13942: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13943: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13943: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13944: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13944: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13946: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:13949: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:13949: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13951: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:13955: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:13915: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13955: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:13955: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:13957: error: syntax error before "while"
mod_wsgi.c:13998: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:13998: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14000: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:13955: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14000: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14000: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14002: error: syntax error before "break"
mod_wsgi.c:14005: error: conflicting types for 'name'
mod_wsgi.c:13953: error: previous declaration of 'name' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14005: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14005: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14007: error: syntax error before '(' token
mod_wsgi.c:14010: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14010: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14011: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14013: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14013: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14014: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14040: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:13930: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14040: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14040: error: invalid type argument of `->'
mod_wsgi.c:14040: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14040: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14042: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14049: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:13924: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14049: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14049: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14049: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14050: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14050: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14051: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14053: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14053: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14054: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14054: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14058: error: syntax error before '(' token
mod_wsgi.c:14080: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14082: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14082: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14084: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c: In function `wsgi_allow_access':
mod_wsgi.c:14093: error: invalid operands to binary *
mod_wsgi.c:14095: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14143: error: `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS' undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14143: error: syntax error before "apr_thread_mutex_lock"
mod_wsgi.c:14147: error: `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS' undeclared (first use in this fu nction)
mod_wsgi.c:14150: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14152: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14161: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:14178: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14187: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14187: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14192: error: redefinition of 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:8689: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14192: error: redefinition of 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:2274: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14192: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14196: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14198: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14049: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14198: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14198: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14200: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:13923: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14200: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:8509: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14200: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14201: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14198: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14201: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14201: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14201: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14203: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14205: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:13940: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14205: error: redefinition of 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14205: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14206: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14206: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14207: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14207: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:14040: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14207: error: redefinition of 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14207: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14209: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14209: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:13934: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14209: error: redefinition of 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14209: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14211: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:14209: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14211: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14211: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a c ast
mod_wsgi.c:14211: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14211: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14213: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14216: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14216: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14217: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:14205: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14217: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14217: error: `host' undeclared here (not in a function)
mod_wsgi.c:14217: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14217: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14218: error: conflicting types for 'flag'
mod_wsgi.c:14206: error: previous definition of 'flag' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14218: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14218: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14219: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14219: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14220: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14220: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14221: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14221: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14223: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14256: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:14207: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14256: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14256: error: invalid type argument of `->'
mod_wsgi.c:14256: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14256: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14258: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14265: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14201: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14265: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14265: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14265: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14266: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14266: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14267: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14269: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14269: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14270: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14270: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14274: error: syntax error before '(' token
mod_wsgi.c:14296: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14298: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14298: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14300: error: syntax error before "return"
mod_wsgi.c: In function `wsgi_hook_check_user_id':
mod_wsgi.c:14345: error: invalid operands to binary *
mod_wsgi.c:14347: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14393: error: `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS' undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14393: error: syntax error before "apr_thread_mutex_lock"
mod_wsgi.c:14397: error: `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS' undeclared (first use in this fu nction)
mod_wsgi.c:14400: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14402: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14411: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:14428: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14437: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14437: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14442: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:14000: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14442: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14442: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14446: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14448: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14265: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14448: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14448: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14450: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:14200: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14450: error: redefinition of 'module_dict'
mod_wsgi.c:8509: error: previous definition of 'module_dict' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14450: error: syntax error before "module"
mod_wsgi.c:14451: error: conflicting types for 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14448: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14451: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14451: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14451: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14453: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14455: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:14217: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14455: error: redefinition of 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14455: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14456: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14456: error: conflicting types for 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:14192: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14456: error: conflicting types for 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:2274: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14456: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14457: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14457: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:14256: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14457: error: redefinition of 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14457: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14459: error: syntax error before '*' token
mod_wsgi.c:14459: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:14211: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14459: error: redefinition of 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14459: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14461: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:14459: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14461: error: conflicting types for 'adapter'
mod_wsgi.c:8507: error: previous definition of 'adapter' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14461: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a c ast
mod_wsgi.c:14461: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14461: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14463: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14466: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14466: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14467: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:14455: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14467: error: conflicting types for 'args'
mod_wsgi.c:5299: error: previous definition of 'args' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14467: error: `password' undeclared here (not in a function)
mod_wsgi.c:14467: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14467: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14468: error: conflicting types for 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:14456: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14468: error: redefinition of 'result'
mod_wsgi.c:2274: error: previous definition of 'result' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14468: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14468: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14469: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14469: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14470: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14470: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14471: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14471: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14473: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14477: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:14442: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14477: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14477: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14479: error: syntax error before string constant
mod_wsgi.c:14483: error: conflicting types for 'ap_log_rerror'
/usr/include/httpd/http_log.h:202: error: previous declaration of 'ap_log_rerror ' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14483: error: conflicting types for 'ap_log_rerror'
/usr/include/httpd/http_log.h:202: error: previous declaration of 'ap_log_rerror ' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14483: error: conflicting types for 'r'
mod_wsgi.c:2824: error: previous declaration of 'r' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14483: error: syntax error before '->' token
mod_wsgi.c:14493: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:14477: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14493: error: redefinition of 'status'
mod_wsgi.c:6515: error: previous definition of 'status' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14493: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14495: error: syntax error before string constant
mod_wsgi.c:14499: error: syntax error before '->' token
mod_wsgi.c:14508: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14508: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14509: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14523: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:14457: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14523: error: conflicting types for 'method'
mod_wsgi.c:8516: error: previous definition of 'method' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14523: error: invalid type argument of `->'
mod_wsgi.c:14523: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14523: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14525: error: syntax error before "if"
mod_wsgi.c:14532: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:14451: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14532: error: redefinition of 'object'
mod_wsgi.c:4717: error: previous definition of 'object' was here
mod_wsgi.c:14532: error: initializer element is not constant
mod_wsgi.c:14532: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14533: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14533: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14534: error: syntax error before '}' token
mod_wsgi.c:14536: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14536: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14537: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14537: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14541: error: syntax error before '(' token
mod_wsgi.c:14563: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14565: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declarati on
mod_wsgi.c:14565: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
mod_wsgi.c:14567: error: syntax error before "return"
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a configuration problem. Of course, you haven't told us anything about your configuration. Consider supplying details such as OS, word size, apache version, installed libraries, and mod_wsgi version.

Comment: word size? really? might as well ask for the CPU temperature and the wind speed.

Answer (score 1):

You likely haven't go either python-dev or httpd-dev package installed and so compilation cant find their header files. Read requirements for what needs to be installed in the README of the mod_wsgi source code.